# Wordpress URL Rewrite with QueryString

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm just kind of beginning the WordPress experience. I have a site using out-of-the-box WordPress search, and the default behavior as I understand it, to pick the query string `s` from the request by convention to execute the actual search.

This means the URL after a search will look something like `domain/?s=whatever`, which works fine as far as searching is concerned.

I would like, however, the search page to have a URL of it's own, more like `domain/search?s=whatever`.

I'm attempting to achieve the above using URL rewriting, and have tried several different `htaccess` configurations, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /base_whatever
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.*)$
RewriteRule search ?? [NC,L]
```

The above configuration is the baseline, and alternatives I've tried for `??` includes the following:

- /base_whatever
- /base_whatever?s=%1
- .

I'm sure much of the above would seem hilarious to one that has experience with Apache and such, but there you have it. I tried a myriad of different even more awkward variations, but all of them yields a `404` response in my case.

Since the actual search script, my `search.php` file, is located inside my WordPress themes folder, I put a `test.php` file in the same location, and sure enough, I can redirect the request to that one just fine:

- `RewriteRule search /base_whatever/wp-content/themes/foo/test.php` -> success

So, I also tried the full path to my `search.php`, but that makes WordPress barf:

- `RewriteRule search /base_whatever/wp-content/themes/foo/search.php` -> fail

It would seem that WordPress has trouble executing the "content include stuff" out of context like that (the functions are not available).

By the by, the rest of the `htaccess` file is standard WordPress/PHP stuff i guess, like:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /base_whatever/index.php [L]
```

Hopefully, there's a simple way to achieve this basic task, but as you can tell I'm having a bit of a problem realizing it. I checked several blogs on the topic, such as [this one](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/) which seems reasonable, but still can't get it to work, so can you guys and girls please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Because most of what WordPress does is essentially creating virtual pages from content stored in a database (ie there isn't a physical file / page on the server, it handles a lot of redirection stuff internally.

Hence setting up rewrite rules in htaccess can be a real head-banging situation. Luckily, the WP API has a number of hooks for doing rewrites. In your case you need to use the '' hook. The following should work for you, but is fairly straightforward, so customising it shouldn't be a problem.

**OPTION 1:**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so47156599' ) );

function so47156599() {

    if ( is_search() and false === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_bloginfo( 'home' ) . '/search/' . str_replace( ' ', '+', str_replace( '%20', '+', get_query_var( 's' ) ) ) );
        exit();
    }

}
```

**OPTION 2:**

Alternatively, you could take a look at the [API options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/search_rewrite_rules).

**OPTION 3:**

A .htaccess based opttion might be:

```
# search redirection
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

This should take anything in the query string, minus any extraneous values, and turn them into a clean working url. You may need to place this above (or below) the default WordPress rewrite rules for it to work. (I can't test it at the moment.)

Comment: Thank you for answering :) I realize that `wp_redirect()` could be an option. I'd prefer just rewriting the URL though, and at the least I'd like to understand why I'm failing, before switching my approach.

Comment: Because, WP already does a lot of rewriting. Getting around the WP rewrites without messing things up is a very tricky option.

Comment: @OskarLindberg I've added an additional option using the .htaccess file approach.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these options, which looks a lot like some things I've tried but with small and possibly important differences. For completeness, in your `htaccess` option, the `RewriteCond` regex should probably be `\\?s=([^&#]+)`, right?